# What's the /home directory for, or did I just accidentally create it?

Tags: macos, bash

I saw reference to a bash command, `cd /home`, in a multiple choice quiz about navigating within Terminal. I tried it, expecting `-bash: cd: /home: No such file or directory`, but to my surprise it took me to a top level directory /home. I don't know if it just created the directory or if it was already there, or if it's a temporary thing or what.

I've googled around for info on the hidden top level directories (/var, /usr, /private, /etc, ...) but none mention a /home directory. Using `ls -al` from / yields (omitting all but the relevant line):

```
dr-xr-xr-x   2 root  wheel        1 Sep  6 15:57 home
```

and a `ls -al` from within /home yields

```
total 2
dr-xr-xr-x   2 root  wheel     1 Sep  6 15:57 .
drwxr-xr-x  30 root  wheel  1088 Aug 17 17:17 ..
```

I was surprised at how hard it was to track down a comprehensive (or even partial) directory tree showing what/where stuff is (beyond what shows up in Finder).

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: I did some research into what `/home` is for on OS X here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/87052/21050 (scroll down to my answer; it doesn't seem to jump there automatically)

Comment: @zigg Thanks! It's good to know it's supposed to be there. I'd mark your comment as an answer if I could.

Comment: Yeah, /home is there -- like it or not -- I actually don't like it being there.  I'll read up on the answer above.  I do want to mention that now I like to see all of the hiddent files and folders by issuing the following command: defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE Once you issue this command, you can see all kinds of Unixy things in the Finder.